# How to read the facebook notification count in android

Tags: android, facebook, notifications, android-notifications

Hi am working on a project in which i need to show the notification.

I used "NotificationListenerService" and i struct in the facebook notification account[image]

I need to show the notification count in my app.

Need to show inside my app " Facebook has 15 notifications.."

help me to finish this

Comment: I need to show inside notification in my app, need to get programatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display unread count to the android app icon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285155/how-to-display-unread-count-to-the-android-app-icon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since v2.4 of the Graph API, you can´t access the notifications (or the unread count) anymore. In other words, what you want to achieve is not possible.

Changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4